# How do I share my wireless internet connection over Ethernet?

Tags: windows-xp, ethernet, bridge, wireless-networking

I want to achieve the same thing with Windows XP that I do with Mac OS X. On my Mac I use "Internet Sharing" from "Wi-Fi" to "Ethernet".

What I'm trying to do is connect my freesat top-set box to my wireless connection. The Freesat box only has a wired ethernet connection.

What I want to do is connect my laptop ethernet connection to the freesat-box ethernet connection and share my laptop's wifi to the laptops ethernet connection

Edit:
Also I need the laptop or the wifi DCHP server to address the freesat-box.

Comment: Is wiring impossible? It looks non feasible to have your laptop on for your Freesat box.

Comment: No. Unfortunately not. My concept works on my Mac but I'm struggling with Win XP.

Comment: @Simon: Sorry Simon I don't understand. Is it "Internet-->Freesat==>something-->laptop" or is it "Internet-->Freesat==>laptop==>something-->others"? Or is it "Internet==>wifirouter-->laptop==>something==>Freesat"? ("--" is wired, "==" is wireless).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called Internet Connection Sharing in Windows XP. There is a nice tutorial [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306126).

Excerpt:

> On the host computer:
>
> - Log on to the host computer as Administrator or as Owner.
> - Click Start, and then click Control Panel.
> - Click Network and Internet Connections.
> - Click Network Connections.
> - Right-click the connection that you use to connect to the Internet. For example, if you - connect to the Internet by using a modem, right-click the connection that you want under Dial-up.
> - Click Properties.
> - Click the Advanced tab.
> - Under Internet Connection Sharing, select the Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection check box.

On the client computer:

> - Log on to the client computer as Administrator or as Owner.
> - Click Start, and then click Control Panel.
> - Click Network and Internet Connections.
> - Click Network Connections.
> - Right-click Local Area Connection, and then click Properties.
> - Click the General tab, click Internet Protocol (TCP/IP) in the This connection uses the following items list, and then click Properties.
> - In the Internet Protocol (TCP/IP) Properties dialog box, click Obtain an IP address automatically (if it is not already selected), and then click OK.